# The easiest way to remove the bidirectional recursive relationships?

Tags: java, recursion, gson

I use the [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)  library to convert Java objects to a Json response...
the problem is that after a JPA requests the object retrieved from DB can not be converted because of a recursive relationship with other entities([see my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10027268/how-to-serialize-a-java-util-liste-to-json-using-gson-library)) for example :

```
public class Gps implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "IMEI", nullable = false, length = 20)
    private String imei;
    //some code here...
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "gpsImei", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Coordonnees> coordonneesList;


public class Coordonnees implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "IDCOORDONNEES", nullable = false)
    private Integer idcoordonnees;
    //some code here...
    @JoinColumn(name = "GPS_IMEI", referencedColumnName = "IMEI", nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Gps gpsImei;
```

My source code:

```
  EntityManagerFactory emf=Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("JavaApplication21PU");
  GpsJpaController gjc=new GpsJpaController(emf);

  Gps gps=gjc.findGps("123456789012345");

  for(int i=0;i<gps.getCoordonneesList().size();i++){
   gps.getCoordonneesList().get(i).setGpsImei(null);
  }  

  Gson gson=new Gson();
  String json=gson.toJson(gps);//convert to json response

  System.out.println(json);
```

As you can see here i made :

```
   for(int i=0;i<gps.getCoordonneesList().size();i++){
     gps.getCoordonneesList().get(i).setGpsImei(null);
   }
```

only to kill the recursive relationship by setting null for each GPS object in the coordonneesList..

In your opinion this is a good solution or is there another method more practical?
Thanks

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There's a Gson extension called [GraphAdapterBuilder](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/1d9e86e27c97cd85d898104b4ac42bb487d0d7d0/extras/src/main/java/com/google/gson/graph/GraphAdapterBuilder.java) that can serialize objects that contain circular references. Here's a very simplified example from the corresponding test case:

```
Roshambo rock = new Roshambo("ROCK");
Roshambo scissors = new Roshambo("SCISSORS");
Roshambo paper = new Roshambo("PAPER");
rock.beats = scissors;
scissors.beats = paper;
paper.beats = rock;

GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
new GraphAdapterBuilder()
    .addType(Roshambo.class)
    .registerOn(gsonBuilder);
Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
System.out.println(gson.toJson(rock));
```

This prints:

```
{
  '0x1': {'name': 'ROCK', 'beats': '0x2'},
  '0x2': {'name': 'SCISSORS', 'beats': '0x3'},
  '0x3': {'name': 'PAPER', 'beats': '0x1'}
}
```

Note that the GraphAdapterBuilder class is **not** included in gson.jar. If you want to use it, you'll have to copy it into your project manually.

Comment: Thanks! This was a lifesaver when working with hibernate. Saved me a bunch of trouble when converting an hibernate entity using gson.

Comment: which jar contains this "GraphAdapterBuilder" class ?

Comment: The json string is properly builded, but the references don't seem to be working. How can access a property like 0x1.beats.name --> output should be 'SCISSORS'? So jump within the object graph.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem by myself. If you have a similar problem please check: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22788445/2182503

Comment: awesome, saved me lots of time. For future reference, just copy the GraphAdapterBuilder source from: [ https://github.com/google/gson/blob/1d9e86e27c97cd85d898104b4ac42bb487d0d7d0/extras/src/main/java/com/google/gson/graph/GraphAdapterBuilder.java ]  and use it directly in your project

Comment: Someone added gson-extras to maven central in the mean time; 

For Gradle: `compile 'org.danilopianini:gson-extras:0.2.1'`

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about with Gson but I'm working with Jackson. Look up an example of using its ObjectMapper class. As for the recursion, use @JsonManagedReference and @JsonBackReference to stop that. Look those up for example usage too.

Answer (score 2):

I would configure GsonBuilder to work with jackson annotations:

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder()
    .addSerializationExclusionStrategy(serializationExclusionStrategy);

final ExclusionStrategy serializationExclusionStrategy = new ExclusionStrategy() {
  @Override
  public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
    return f.getAnnotation(JsonIgnore.class) != null
           || f.getAnnotation(JsonBackReference.class) != null;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> aClass) {
    return false;
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, man. This worked perfectly for me. Even though you posted it in 2014 and I used it in 2020. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use @Expose(serialize = false) to avoid the Collection to be serialized.

Answer (score 1):

Use **transient** for ignoring  @OneToMany sets for google.gson

Comment: if you do so, OneToMany association will be ignored by most of JPA implementations.