# Make Gson behavior depth-dependent

Tags: java, serialization, gson

Is there a sane way of making Gson handling nested objects differently from those at the top level? Things to be serialized are entities and they all have an `id`. A nested entity should be replaced by its `id` (to shorten the output and possibly fight endless recursion).

Let's say there's a

```
@AllArgsConstructor class User {
    int id;
    String name;
    User parent;
}
```

and I execute

```
User grampa = new User(3, "Grampa", null);
User homer = new User(2, "Homer", grampa);
User bart = new User(1, "Bart", homer);
```

What I get when serializing `bart` is

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: "Bart",
    father: {
        id: 2,
        name: "Homer",
        father: {
            id: 3,
            name: "Grampa"
        }
    }
}
```

which is much more than I need. I actually never want to serialize nested entities, their `id`s are good enough.

Using a <strike>global</strike> thread-local variable hack and a `TypeAdapterFactory` I can get

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: "Bart",
    father: 2,
}
```

which is nearly what I want. I'd prefer `fatherId` to `father` and I'd surely prefer something less hacky than a global variable.

I don't want to create a DAO, scan the object reflexively or alike (then I could do the whole serialization myself, couldn't I?).

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding the transformation. It feels like a lot of information has disappeared.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Better now?

Comment: Do you want Jackson's [object identity](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureObjectIdentity) for Gson? The Gson extension [GraphAdapterBuilder](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10036958/880772) let you kinda do that.

Answer (score 1):

The [Gson documentation](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Sharing-State-Across-Custom-Serializers-and-Deserializers) I think points the way to a "saner" approach. Create a `TypeAdapter` factory which encapsulates state and returns an inner class `TypeAdapter` instance referencing that state, something like this:

```
public class UserTypeAdapterFactory {
    private Set<Integer> serializedUsers = new HashSet<>();

    public JsonSerializer<User> getTypeAdapter() {
        return (user, type, context) -> {
            JsonObject el = new JsonObject();
            el.addProperty("id", user.getId());
            el.addProperty("name", user.getName());

            if(user.getFather() != null) {
                JsonArray els = new JsonArray();
                int fatherId = user.getFather().getId();
                if(!serializedUsers.contains(fatherId)) {
                    JsonElement father = context.serialize(user.getFather());
                    if (father.isJsonArray()) {
                        els.addAll(father.getAsJsonArray());
                    } else {
                        els.add(father);
                    }
                    serializedUsers.add(fatherId);
                }
                el.addProperty("fatherId", fatherId);
                els.add(el);
                return els;
            } else {
                return el;
            }
        };
    }
}

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .registerTypeAdapter(
        User.class, 
        new UserTypeAdapterFactory().getTypeAdapter())
    .build();
System.out.println(gson.toJson(
    new User(1, "Bart", new User(2, "Homer", new User(3, "Grampa", null)))));
```

Which should print:

```
[{"id":3,"name":"Grampa"},{"id":2,"name":"Homer","fatherId":3},{"id":1,"name":"Bart","fatherId":2}]
```

Comment: It's nice, but it does what I wanted to avoid, namely fooling around with the fields myself. I want this for all entities and all their members without enumerating them. +++ As written, it can't do the expected thing as `serializedUsers` gets only tested and written, but never used otherwise. But I've got the idea and this can be fixed. +++ It also makes the `gson` instance context dependent and forces me to use it per request/session rather than as a singleton. But let's call it a feature.

Comment: It's a proof of concept. The key part is the context dependence. The set is a context that lets you know whether you need to serialize the father. The problem is that the serializer is registered at the top level, which makes the context global. Another option is to create a proxy of `JsonElement` which allows local context.